# Как устанавливать npm без sudo?

Tags: macos, npm, sudo

Каждый раз для установки нового проекта приходится ставить таким образом
*sudo npm i*
Как можно от этого избавиться? Без sudo ошибки пишет

Система **Mojave**

При вводе команды **npm i** выводится следующее

```
npm ERR! path /Users/mak/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T06_33_23_577Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink 
'/Users/mak/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T06_33_23_577Z-debug.log'
npm ERR!     at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:949:3)
npm ERR!     at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:306:17)
npm ERR!     at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:336:20
npm ERR!     at f (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
npm ERR!     at Glob.<anonymous> (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:151:7)
npm ERR!     at Glob.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at Glob._finish (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:197:8)
npm ERR!     at done (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:182:14)
npm ERR!     at Glob._processReaddir2 (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:434:12)
npm ERR!     at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:371:17
npm ERR!     at RES (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:31:16)
npm ERR!     at f (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
npm ERR!     at Glob._readdirEntries (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:578:10)
npm ERR!     at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:555:12
npm ERR!     at go$readdir$cb (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:149:14)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
npm ERR!  { Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink '/Users/mak/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T06_33_23_577Z-debug.log'
npm ERR!     at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:949:3)
npm ERR!     at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:306:17)
npm ERR!     at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:336:20
npm ERR!     at f (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
npm ERR!     at Glob.<anonymous> (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:151:7)
npm ERR!     at Glob.emit (events.js:182:13)
npm ERR!     at Glob._finish (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:197:8)
npm ERR!     at done (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:182:14)
npm ERR!     at Glob._processReaddir2 (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:434:12)
npm ERR!     at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:371:17
npm ERR!     at RES (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:31:16)
npm ERR!     at f (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)
npm ERR!     at Glob._readdirEntries (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:578:10)
npm ERR!     at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:555:12
npm ERR!     at go$readdir$cb (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:149:14)
npm ERR!     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, unlink \'/Users/mak/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T06_33_23_577Z-debug.log\'\n    at Object.unlinkSync (fs.js:949:3)\n    at Function.rimrafSync [as sync] (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js:306:17)\n    at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/npm.js:336:20\n    at f (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)\n    at Glob.<anonymous> (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:151:7)\n    at Glob.emit (events.js:182:13)\n    at Glob._finish (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:197:8)\n    at done (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:182:14)\n    at Glob._processReaddir2 (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:434:12)\n    at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:371:17\n    at RES (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/inflight/inflight.js:31:16)\n    at f (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/once/once.js:25:25)\n    at Glob._readdirEntries (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:578:10)\n    at /Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/glob/glob.js:555:12\n    at go$readdir$cb (/Users/mak/.nvm/versions/node/v10.12.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:149:14)\n    at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:141:20)',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/mak/.npm/_logs/2018-10-22T06_33_23_577Z-debug.log' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
npm ERR! path /Users/mak/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-21167e59
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/mak/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-21167e59'
npm ERR!  { [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/mak/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-21167e59']
npm ERR!   cause:
npm ERR!    { Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/Users/mak/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-21167e59'
npm ERR!      errno: -13,
npm ERR!      code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!      syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!      path: '/Users/mak/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-21167e59' },
npm ERR!   stack:
npm ERR!    'Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir \'/Users/mak/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-21167e59\'',
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/Users/mak/.npm/_cacache/tmp/git-clone-21167e59',
npm ERR!   parent: 'gulp-html-prettify' }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).
```

Comment: давайте разбираться - вы установили `npm install -g` - после чего вы создаете проект в нужной вам папке, вы используете `npm i --save-dev` ?

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич вероятно всего изначально установил npm install -g (дело было год назад) В нужной папке использую sudo npm i --allow-root (без sudo вот что выводит http://take.ms/xVBB1)

Comment: Если без sudo ошибки пишет, значит вы что-то уже успели сломать, потому что без sudo всё тоже должно работать. Лучше покажите, какие именно ошибки пишет-то (и точные команды, потому что на вашем скриншоте из предыдущего комментария команд не видно) (и тексты должны быть текстом, а не скриншотами)

Comment: @andreymal обновил

Comment: Ну по-моему это совершенно не нормально. Если у вас ещё не установленно ничего сверхценного, попробуйте удалить всё командой вроде `sudo rm -rf /Users/mak/.npm` и потом набрать `npm i` заново без всяких sudo

Answer (score 1):

## Глобальная установка npm пакетов без sudo в macOS и Linux

По умолчанию npm устанавливает пакеты для текущего проекта. Иногда нужно установить пакет глобально, например консольное приложение (`npm install -g <пакет>`). Неудобство в том, что во многих системах приходится запускать эту команду под root (или использовать `sudo`).

Этим способом вы можете установить пакет глобально для текущего пользователя без sudo:

1. Создаем каталог для глобальных пакетов:

   `mkdir "${HOME}/.npm-packages"`
2. Указываем `npm` где искать глобально установленные пакеты. Добавляем в файл `~/.npmrc`:

   `prefix=${HOME}/.npm-packages`
3. Делаем npm пакеты доступными из командной строки. В домашнем каталоге пользователя найдите один из файлов `.profile`/`.bashrc`/`.zshrc`/`.bash_profile` (зависит от установленной системы) и добавьте в него:

   `export PATH="${PATH}:${HOME}/.npm-packages"`
4. Перезапускаем терминал.

---

Также, рекомендую ознакомиться с документацией:
["Fixing npm permissions"](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions).

Answer (score 0):

Флаг `-g` ставит пакет глобально, для этого нужны рут права. Можно поставить и локально в проект, без этого флага